# envelopesApi.createRecipientView() of docusign keep return 400 Bad request error

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

here are my code

```
    let viewRequest = new docuSign.RecipientViewRequest();
    viewRequest.returnUrl = this.returnUrl;
    viewRequest.authenticationMethod = "none";
    viewRequest.email = signerEmail;
    viewRequest.userName = signerName;
    viewRequest.clientUserId = this.clientUserId; //?
    viewRequest.pingFrequency = 600;
    console.log("view request", viewRequest);
    console.log("accountInfo.apiAccountId", accountInfo.apiAccountId);
    console.log("envelopeId", envelopeId);
    result = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(
    accountInfo.apiAccountId,
    envelopeId,
    {
    recipientViewRequest: viewRequest,
    }
    );
```

it keep return 400 error bad request

```
    returnUrl="www.google.com"
    clientUserId=1;
    signerEmail = "tranleha1710@gmail.com";
    signerName = "tran le ha";
```

here is the signer i used for envelope

```
    let signer = docuSign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    email: envelopeArgs.signerEmail,
    name: envelopeArgs.signerName,
    recipientId: "1",
    clientUserId: this.clientUserId,
    });
```

the apiAccountId i used for both envelope is the same and i use jwt grant authenticate

Can any one help me fix this, i dont know what iam doing wrong

Comment: Well, you set `viewRequest.returnUrl = this.returnUrl`, but you set `returUrl = "www.google.com"` instead of `returnUrl="www.google.com"`.

Comment: sadly, the problem still the same T^T

Comment: ***Welcome! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0):

1. Try setting

```
    viewRequest.returnUrl = "https://google.com";
```

2. Provide the error message from the response. You can use [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) for this.

Comment: i have changed the returnURL as you said, it still have the same error, and i checked the log, it all ok except GetUserProfileImage is not found, thats all

Comment: please add the api log (xxx out any private info) to your question -- edit you question to add it.